# CodeMirror 2 - wrong editor height after a hidden textarea unhides

Tags: javascript, forms, show-hide, codemirror

so I have a textarea surrounded by a DIV container:

```
<div>
  <textarea id="code"> some text here </textarea>
</div>
```

and this textarea is tranformed into a code editor using CodeMirror:

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea('code', {
  lineNumbers: true,
  matchBrackets: true,
  mode: 'text/html'
});
```

the problem is that when the container of the textarea is hidden (some times it is, depending on what the user chooses to display), then after toggling to unhide it the CodeMirror editor doesn't appear like it should. It only shows one line, and you have to actually click inside it to redraw and show properly.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **refresh()**
>   If your code does something to change the size of the editor element (window resizes are already listened for), or unhides it, you should probably follow up by calling this method to ensure CodeMirror is still looking as intended.

from [CodeMirror manual](http://codemirror.net/manual.html#refresh) *(assuming you're using version 2)*

Comment: thanks, I didn't think I needed refresh, because I'm hidding and showing other containers of the HTML above, and the codemirror seems to work for them

Comment: Actually, that does not work.  I have tried multiple types of refresh() and it does not work.  I am using Bootstrap for my UI.  I have the CodeMirror textarea in a modal "dialog" that pops up.  When that happens the text area is hidden, and I get what looks to be a single line shown.  After clicking in te area, then it repaints.